# Returning a computed element with computed attribute

Tags: xquery

I am trying to return a computed element with a computed attribute.  I have Google'd and RTFM'd this.

Assume the element name and attribute name are in variables:

```
let $elname := "book"
let $attrname := "title"
```

I know I can create an element with:

```
element {$elname} {'content'}
```

and an attribute:

```
attribute {$attrname} {'value'}
```

But how do I create:

```
<book title="something"/>
```

I've tried every permutation I can imagine.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
element {$elname} {attribute {$attrname} {'something'}}
```

Here's an example of `<book>` also containing content:

```
element {$elname} {attribute {$attrname} {'something'},'foo'}
```

This would produce:

```
<book title="something">foo</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out:

```
return element {'joe'} { attribute {'x'} {'e'}, 'z' }
```